# Swift xcode 8 - Using multiple buttons and audio files

Tags: swift, xcode, button, audio

New to Swift and Xcode - Need help playing multiple audio files with more than one buttons. I have been able to get it to play a single file with one of the buttons but don't wish to write the entire program for each button!

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // address of the music file
        let music = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "File1", ofType: "mp3")

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: music! ))
        }
        catch{
            print("error")
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func Play(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }


    @IBAction func stop(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioPlayer.currentTime = 0
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var myVolumeController: UISlider!

    @IBAction func controlVolume(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        audioPlayer.volume = myVolumeController.value
    }
}
```

Comment: set the unique `tag` to each UIButton. In common method(say `playSongWithTag:`), initialise the `audioPlayer`. Set the resource name depending upon tag value.

Answer (score 0):

Class structure is best choose for you (swift 3) :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class BUTTON   {


class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "nib file name", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}

var SELF :UIView
var buttonText : String

let BTN  = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom) as UIButton

// CONSTRUCT INIT
init ( UIView_ :  UIView , buttonText_ : String ) {

    print("Button instance constructor")
    SELF = UIView_;
    buttonText = buttonText_;

}

func CREATE_BUTTON () {

    BTN.setTitle(buttonText, for: UIControlState.normal )
    BTN.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    BTN.frame.origin.x = 10
    BTN.frame.origin.y = 100
    BTN.frame.size = CGSize(width: 155, height: 155 )
    BTN.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)
    BTN.setTitleColor( UIColor.black  , for: UIControlState.normal )
    SELF.addSubview(BTN)

    //let image = UIImage(named: "name") as UIImage?

    //BTN.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    //BTN.addTarget(self, action: "btnTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)


}}
```

Use it like this :

let MyButton1 = BUTTON(  UIView_ : self.view ,  buttonText_ : "Nidza")

- self.view can be also custom view or any other view

In your example you can put new option in init like PLAYER .
Every button will come with own player (to looks like sound mixer).

Comment: Thank you all, I was able to get it working by adding the file path variable to each UIButton as follows -

Comment: @IBAction func playAudio4(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let music = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Audio4", ofType: "mp3")
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: music! ))
        }
        catch{
            print("error")
        }
        audioPlayer.play()
    }